# Picture preview shows nothing by the stock picture

Tags: windows-7, photos

My wife's desktop is experiencing something odd.  When she clicks on the Pictures item from the Start menu, every photo it shows, is all of the stock photo of a daisy.  All the same.  Even if she's got the preview pane up, that's all it shows.  Why is that?

She's got Windows 7 Home Premium installed, 64-bit with SP1.  It is a HP desktop, and is about a year old. Came with Windws 7 installed.

Comment: Sounds like thumbnailing is disabled. When you double-click, does the picture open?

Comment: Yes, double-clicking on any image file opens it up fine.